# Non-recursive permutations and strings generator

Tags: c#, performance, combinatorics

Inspired by [Sam](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/104003/59161)'s question ([Brute-force string generator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104003/brute-force-string-generator)) and [rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/104034/59161)'s really short version of the algorithm I started to experiment with a different approach and created one that seems to run a little bit faster (about 40-50ms for a string of length 4). As it doesn't really optimize the orginal algorithm but is a complete different one I thought I let you review it.

Actually it's really simple although it requires signifficantly more code then the original example and expecially the opmizided one.

To generate the permutations I wrote an `Odometer` class with a `RolloverCounter` that works like an odometer in a car. Each odometer gear-value is an index in the `charSet` array so based on these indexes I create a string.

It doesn't run in parallel yet but I made some preparations to implement it later. The `RolloverCounter` and the `Odometer` can start at some random number and continue from there so the whole range of possible permutations can be devided into sub-odometers and run on different threads.

I also shortened the char array to be generated from ascii codes and allowed the user to specify which character set he would like to use.

---

## `CharSets`

```
[Flags]
public enum CharSets
{
    Lowercase,
    Uppercase,
    Numbers,
    Special
}
```

---

## `RolloverCounter`

```
public class RolloverCounter
{
    private readonly int _min;
    private readonly int _max;
    private int _value;

    public RolloverCounter(int min, int max, int value)
    {
        _min = min;
        _max = max;
        _value = value;
    }

    public RolloverCounter(int min, int max) : this(min, max, min)
    {
    }

    public int Value { get { return _value; } }

    // increases the counter and returns true if rolledover
    public bool Increase()
    {
        if (++_value < _max)
        {
            return false;
        }
        _value = _min;
        return true;
    }

    // makes things easier
    public static explicit operator int (RolloverCounter rolloverCounter)
    {
        return rolloverCounter._value;
    }
}
```

---

## `Odometer`

```
public class Odometer
{
    private readonly int _gearCount;
    private readonly int _min;
    private readonly int _max;

    public Odometer(int gearCount, int min, int max, params int[] gearValues)
    {
        _gearCount = gearCount;
        _min = min;
        _max = max;
        Gears =
            gearValues.Length > 0
            // start at the specified state - for multithreading
            ? gearValues.Select(x => new RolloverCounter(min, max, x)).ToList()
            // start at min
            : new List<RolloverCounter>(gearCount) { new RolloverCounter(min, max) };
        Max = max;
    }

    public int Max { get; private set; }

    public List<RolloverCounter> Gears { get; private set; }

    // increases the odometer and returns true if rolledover
    public bool Increase()
    {
        var gear = 0;
        while (gear < Gears.Count && Gears[gear].Increase())
        {
            gear++;

            // add new gear
            if (Gears.Count - 1 < gear)
            {
                Gears.Add(new RolloverCounter(_min, _max, _min));
                break;
            }
        };

        // rollover
        return gear == _gearCount;
    }
}
```

---

## `StringGenerator`

```
public class StringGenerator
{
    private readonly char[] _charSet;

    public StringGenerator(CharSets charSets = CharSets.Lowercase)
    {
        var chars = Enumerable.Empty<char>();

        if (charSets.HasFlag(CharSets.Lowercase))
        {
            chars = chars.Concat(Enumerable.Range(97, 122 - 97 + 1).Select(c => (char)c));
        }

        if (charSets.HasFlag(CharSets.Uppercase))
        {
            chars = chars.Concat(Enumerable.Range(65, 90 - 65 + 1).Select(c => (char)c));
        }

        if (charSets.HasFlag(CharSets.Numbers))
        {
            chars = chars.Concat(Enumerable.Range(48, 57 - 48 + 1).Select(c => (char)c));
        }

        _charSet = chars.ToArray();

        // shorter char set for debugging
        //charSet = Enumerable.Range(97, 99 - 97 + 1).Select(c => (char)c).ToArray();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GenerateStrings(int count)
    {
        // todo: here I'll need to calc the number of permutations and split the
        // the odometer into ranges


        var odometer = new Odometer(count, 0, _charSet.Length);
        do
        {                
            // this loop seems to be the fastest ways to generate a string
            // I tested a few other options like:
            // new string(odometer.Gears.Select(x => _charSet[(int)x]).ToArray())
            // but they were all much slower

            var result = new StringBuilder(odometer.Gears.Count);
            foreach (var gear in odometer.Gears)
            {
                result.Append(_charSet[(int)gear]);
            }
            yield return result.ToString();
        } while (!odometer.Increase());
    }
}
```

---

## Test code

```
var stringCount = 0;
StopwatchHelper.Measure(() =>
{
    var stringGenerator = new StringGenerator(CharSets.Lowercase | CharSets.Numbers);
    var maxStringLength = 4;
    var strings = stringGenerator.GenerateStrings(maxStringLength).ToList();
    stringCount = strings.Count;
},
sw => Console.WriteLine($"       My: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms"));

// measures @rolfl's optimized version
StopwatchHelper.Measure(() =>
{
    var strings2 = new List<string>();
    var bruteForce3 = new BruteForce3();
    for (var i = 0; i < stringCount; i++)
    {
        var generatedString = bruteForce3.GenerateString();
        strings2.Add(generatedString);
    }
},
sw => Console.WriteLine($"Optimized: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms"));

Console.ReadKey();
```

---

## Helper

```
public static Stopwatch Measure(Action measureAction, Action<Stopwatch> resultAction = null)
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    measureAction();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    resultAction?.Invoke(stopwatch);
    return stopwatch;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[someone](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/mod-team-updates-and-site-status?cb=1) suggested we should deal with the growing number of Zombies...

## Easy Performance Win

The performance measurement is wholly inadequate, and when I run your code as provided it tells me that your code is *slower* than that provided by Rolfl.

Using `BenchmarkDotNet` to get sensible measurements (with the proviso that they are running on my machine, at the same time as it is doing a lot of other work), I can agree your method is faster than that provided by Rolfl, running in `~1.8 s` rather than `~1.5 s` for the 4-length string test.

There is, however, an easy way to do better: you shouldn't be initialising a new `StringBuilder` for each word: create one and clear it as you need. This tiny change halves the runtime for strings of length 4, giving `~700 ms`.

> // this loop seems to be the fastest ways to generate a string

You must have missed the most obvious option: fill an array! There are 2 obvious ways to do this: create a big array and use the appropriate overload of `String..ctor` (1), or create an array of the right length when we need it (2). Neither seems to give any real improvement over the `StringBuilder` for these short strings, certainly not enough to accept the reduction in readability and reusability (the `StringBuilder` method can be easily adapted to work with strings rather than chars, which will be important if non-ASCII-characters are needed) without better measurements.

Table of measurements:

```
|        Method | StringLength |        Mean |      Error |     StdDev |
|-------------- |------------- |------------:|-----------:|-----------:|
|         Rolfl |            3 |    36.57 ms |  0.7292 ms |  1.9590 ms |
|       T3chb0t |            3 |    32.51 ms |  0.6764 ms |  1.9732 ms |
| StringBuilder |            3 |    12.51 ms |  0.2493 ms |  0.7154 ms |
|        Array1 |            3 |    11.20 ms |  0.2233 ms |  0.5882 ms |
|        Array2 |            3 |    10.65 ms |  0.2538 ms |  0.7444 ms |
|         Rolfl |            4 | 1,849.73 ms | 36.1277 ms | 56.2465 ms |
|       T3chb0t |            4 | 1,472.04 ms | 28.1790 ms | 68.0553 ms |
| StringBuilder |            4 |   682.75 ms | 16.3137 ms | 48.1013 ms |
|        Array1 |            4 |   623.12 ms | 14.8381 ms | 43.2836 ms |
|        Array2 |            4 |   679.26 ms | 23.1619 ms | 67.5642 ms |
```

Test code: [gist](https://gist.github.com/VisualMelon/46d8cb1172c642242fb0e8b745230910).

## Char Sets Ranges

The `StringGerator(CharSets)` constructor could be made much tidier by using a `List<T>` to accumulate the results (rather than shuffling `IEnumerable`s), and using a helper method to create Ascii Ranges:

```
private static IEnumerable<char> AsciiRange(char start, char end)
{
    if (end < start)
        throw new ArgumentException("The end character must not occur before the start character");
    // TODO: bounds checks are probably in order

    return Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1).Select(c => (char)c);
}

public StringGenerator(CharSets charSets = CharSets.Lowercase)
{
    var chars = new List<char>();

    if (charSets.HasFlag(CharSets.Lowercase))
    {
        chars.AddRange(AsciiRange('a', 'z'));
    }

    if (charSets.HasFlag(CharSets.Uppercase))
    {
        chars.AddRange(AsciiRange('A', 'Z'));
    }

    if (charSets.HasFlag(CharSets.Numbers))
    {
        chars.AddRange(AsciiRange('0', '9'));
    }

    _charSet = chars.ToArray();
}
```

This is much more maintainable, as there is reduced repetition, and you don't need an ASCII table at hand to make modifications.

## Odometer is not reusable

I also don't like that `Increase` creates a another `RolloverCounter` at the very end of the enumeration: it is basically ignoring `_gearCount`. It has the consequence that when you 'reuse' the odometer, you end up with another gear on the end, and if you use it a few more times, you end up with another gear on the end...

For example, using just `var _charSet = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };`, the time you get the correct output:

`a`, `b`, `c`, `aa`, `ab`, etc.

using it again, you get:

`aaaa`, `baaa`, `caaa`, etc.

And again, the last `a` becomes a `b`... it's a total nightmare. It needs something like this on the end:

```
if (gear == _gearCount)
{
    // rollover
    Gears.RemoveRange(1, Gears.Count - 1);
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

A check to avoid the last gear being added in the first place would avoid an allocation which takes the list over its initial capacity:

```
if (gear < _gearCount)
    Gears.Add(new RolloverCounter(_min, _max, _min));
```

I don't know if reusability is a goal, but if it isn't then it should be documented. Honestly, the behaviour seems a bit weird from the outset, having gears introduced over-time.

## Misc

- I would be strongly inclined to specify the values for the `CharSets` enum since you are using them as default parameters (their values become part of the API, and so changing them becomes a breaking change).
- The constructors for `RolloverCounter` could obvious do with some bounds checking and documentation (e.g. explaining that the 'default' value is the min, and the `max` is an exclusive upper-bound).
- I don't like that `Odometer.Gears` is public, given it is mutable. I'd be strongly inclined to provide a readonly-view of it; however, unfortunately, this does seem to degrade performance.
- `Odometer.Max` is redundant with `Odometer._max`; I can't see any reason not to make it `Max => _max`. It doesn't make much sense to me to provide `Value` and `Max` but not `Min`.
- I'd feel compelled to rename `RolloverCounter.Increase` to `Increment` or `Advance`, but that's pretty subjective. `Increase` feels like it should have a parameter to determine how much by which to increase (which would be a fun extension).

Comment: _your code is slower than that provided by Rolfl_ - but yours is the only review so far... are you sure you wanted to post this answer here? It looks like it's partially on- and off-topic haha

Comment: @t3chb0t I'm sorry, I don't follow! I believe your code _is_ faster that Rolfl's, it's just that when I first ran it with your basic measurement, I got the opposite result! (presumably because it runs yours first, and rather than swap them around I just went straight to BenchmarkDotNet)

Comment: oh, my bad... I now see that I've linked his answer in my question and you are referring to that, sorry, I fogot that ;-) I like the `AsciiRange` thing.

Comment: Did you check the link about the Zombies?

Comment: @Heslacher yes; I'm not sure I follow?

Comment: I thought you meant https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9251/possible-solution-for-zombies-unanswered-questions

Comment: @Heslacher ah, no. I think that was posted after this answer, actually ;)